# Is it possible to set a static arn for DynamoDB stream arn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Is is possible to override the timestamp part of the Dynamodb stream arn when the streaming is enabled to set to some static value?

The pattern for the dynamodb stream arn is:

> arn:aws:dynamodb:region:accountID:table/TableName/stream/timestamp

Can this is created in a way so that when DynamoDB is created from cloudformation to so that instead of timestamp I can add some values/strings of my choice?

> arn:aws:dynamodb:region:accountID:table/TableName/stream/some-string-of-choice/value ?

So that when the streaming is toggled on/off the arn remains the same for lambda polling the stream.

Thanks!

Comment: The latestStreamArn will change if you disable a DynamoDB stream and then re-enable it. Pretty sure the ARN is not configurable.